# how can remove selected tbody with jquery in multiple tbody of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a table and add more tbody in my table with using jquery. Now I want delete selected tbody when click delete button bot my code delete one row and not delete all of selected tbody. How can do it? My code this is:

```
               <div class='row' id="table_container">
            <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12'>
              <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="invoice_table">
                 <thead>

                    <tr>       
                        <th> <input id="check_all" class="formcontrol" type="checkbox"/></th>
                        <td>User Information</td>
                    </tr>

                 </thead> 
                 <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span> <input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>
                        <td>Info</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>       
                        <td> Name</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="name[]" id="name_1" class="form-controlt"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>       
                        <td>Last Name</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="lastname[]" id="lastname_1" class="form-control"></td>
                    </tr>
                 </tbody>  
            </table>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
            <button class="btn btn-danger delete" type="button">- Delete</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success addmore" type="button">+ Add More</button>
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">

        var i=$('table tbody').length+1;
        $(".addmore").on('click',function(){
            html = '<tbody>';
            html = '<tr>';
            html += '<td> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span> <input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>';
            html += '<td>Info</td>';
            html += '</tr>';
            html += '<tr>';
            html += '<td>Name</td>';
            html += '<td><input type="text" name="name[]" id="name_'+i+'" class="form-control"></td>';
            html += '</tr>';
            html += '<tr>';
            html += '<td>Last Name</td>';
            html += '<td><input type="text" name="lastname[]" id="lastname_'+i+'" class="form-control"></td>';
            html += '</tr>';
            html += '</tbody>';
            $('table').append(html);
            i++;
        });

        //to check all checkboxes
        $(document).on('change','#check_all',function(){
            $('input[class=case]:checkbox').prop("checked", $(this).is(':checked'));
        });


        $(".delete").on('click', function(){
            $('.case:checkbox:checked').parents("tr").remove();
            $('#check_all').prop("checked", false); 
        }); 


        </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem stems from this line of code:

```
$('.case:checkbox:checked').parents("tr").remove();
```

`.parents("tr")` selects ancestors of your checkbox that are `<tr>` elements. Try:

```
$(".case:checkbox:checked").closest("tbody").remove();
```

Comment: Thank you but not working your code delete all tbody I want only delete selected tbody.

Comment: That's because you're not actually adding multiple `tbody`.  This code `html = '<tbody>';html = '<tr>';` should have `+= "<tr>"`